# How to send hidden ID value FormData using asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass Hidden ID value `var genericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();` to FromData.But i can't able to pass Id Value.

how to pass the `hdnGenericID` ID value to controller.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.GenericID, new { id = "hdnGenericID" })
```

cs.Html

```
<div class="uploading-container">
        <div class="uploading-container-left">
          <span class="btn btn-rounded btn-file">
            <span>Choose file</span>
               <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
               </span>
          </div><!--.uploading-container-left-->
<div class="uploading-container-right">
    <div class="uploading-container-right-in">
       <div class="col-lg-4">
         <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label semibold">Perview_Image</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <img id="image_upload_preview" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
             <a id="remove" onclick="javascript:ClearFileUploadControl();" style="display: none; cursor: pointer;">Remove</a>
            </fieldset>
           </div>
          <input type="submit" id="btnImageUpload" name="ImageUpload" value="Upload image" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
```

Image Upload:

```
$(function () {
            $('#btnImageUpload').click(function () {
                var data = new FormData();
                var genericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();
                var files = $("#file").get(0).files;

                if (files.length > 0) { data.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]); }
                else {
                    common.showNotification('warning', 'Please select file to upload.', 'top', 'right');
                    return false;
                }
                var extension = $("#file").val().split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
                if (extension != "PNG" && extension != "JPG" && extension != "GIF" && extension != "JPEG") {
                    common.showNotification('warning', 'Imvalid image file format.', 'top', 'right');
                    return false;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../Generic/SaveProfileImage',
                    type: "POST",
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == true) { // if true (1)
                            setTimeout(function () {// wait for 1 secs(2)
                                location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                            }, 1000);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (er) { }

                });
                return false;
            });

        });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveProfileImage()
        {

            try
            {
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
                {
                    var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];
                    HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(pic);
                    var fileName = docId.ToString() + ".png";
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadGenericImage/"), fileName);
                    filebase.SaveAs(path);
                    //return Json("File Saved Successfully.");
                    return Json(new { data = true});
                }
                else { return Json("No File Saved."); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return Json("Error While Saving."); }
        }
```

Comment: Add the hidden value in form data like `data.append("GenericID", genericID);`

Comment: Append to to the `FormData` object - `data.append('yourPropertyName', genericID);`. But then you need a matching parameter or model in the POST method to receive it.

Comment: can you post full code please @Nitesh

Comment: where i add above your code @StephenMuecke

Comment: After `var genericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  `var data = new FormData();
                var genericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();
                data.append("GenericID", genericID);
                var files = $("#file").get(0).files;`  is it correct?

Comment: That's fine. Now add a parameter `int GenericID` in your POST method and it will be bound.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165137/discussion-between-ivin-raj-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the script like this

```
$(function () {
        $('#btnImageUpload').click(function () {
            var data = new FormData();
            var genericID = $("#hdnGenericID").val();
            data.append("GenericID", genericID);
            var files = $("#file").get(0).files;

            if (files.length > 0) { data.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]); }
            else {
                common.showNotification('warning', 'Please select file to upload.', 'top', 'right');
                return false;
            }
            var extension = $("#file").val().split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
            if (extension != "PNG" && extension != "JPG" && extension != "GIF" && extension != "JPEG") {
                common.showNotification('warning', 'Imvalid image file format.', 'top', 'right');
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '../Generic/SaveProfileImage',
                type: "POST",
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == true) { // if true (1)
                        setTimeout(function () {// wait for 1 secs(2)
                            location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                },
                error: function (er) { }

            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

and change the controller like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveProfileImage(string GenericID)
    {

        try
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
            {
                var pic = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];
                HttpPostedFileBase filebase = new HttpPostedFileWrapper(pic);
                var fileName = docId.ToString() + ".png";
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadGenericImage/"), fileName);
                filebase.SaveAs(path);
                //return Json("File Saved Successfully.");
                return Json(new { data = true});
            }
            else { return Json("No File Saved."); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Json("Error While Saving."); }
    }
```

then in controller you will be able to access the value of GenericID.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using FormCollection parameter to controller action method i.e.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveProfileImage(FormCollection form,string GenericID)
{....
}
```

this form will have your hiddenfield value and can access hiddenfield like below

```
var hiddenFieldValue = form["hdnGenericID"] ..
```